# Efficient way to handle/manage around hundreds of threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

We're developing this app that can send commands to smart devices. The smart device connects to the app using ServerSocket. When a device connected, the app will create 2 threads (For sending command and for receiving the response). So if there are 50 devices connected, the app will create 100 threads.

What happens is that if around 60 devices are already connected, their threads are getting killed by the android. There are also instances that when the device disconnects, the app is not able to detect it.

We would like to connect maximum of 200 devices to the app.

So my questions:

1. Is this the correct way or method for this kind of task?
2. How to properly know how much threads the android device can use?
3. What's the efficient way to handle these threads?

Any tips on the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you

The following are the codes:

**ConnectionThread.class**

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Socket socket;
    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
      listener.onStartedListening();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      try{
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        ReceiveThread receiveThread = new ReceiveThread();
        receiveThread.start();
        SendThread sendThrd = new SendThread();
        sendThrd.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The ReceiveThread and SendThread both extends Thread. They handle the sending of command and receiving response from the device.

Comment: You can't combine the two threads into a single thread that handles both functions?

Comment: use thread pool

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with sockets, you can put both of the IO streams on the same thread, so that should at least cut down on the number of threads. As for the disconnect issue, you should have the server send periodic pings and set a timeout interval for responses, after which the connection should be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be to use NanoHTTP https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd This wheel is already implemented i would request you to modify according to your needs.
I have used and it also supports https.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That is why non-blocking IO has been invented and implemented in Java in the form of a [Selector](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0070__Java_Network_Non-Blocking_Socket.htm) since 2002.

The core problem with Threads is that at some point just switching between threads costs more time than the threads itself could ever safe. The most simple solution is to only have a single thread that takes all the requests and decides whether or not to forward them to worker threads. This singular thread can answer all requests that take faster to answer than to spawn a thread on it's own (like echo requests), and let the heavy weight work be done back background threads, that are limited by the amount of cores. So at top you'd have to manage cores * 2 threads in this scenario.

As this is very old technology, there are many libraries available that do this for you already. As mentioned in another answer: reinventing the wheel is not necessary here.